# Is it possible to limit results returned by a join?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I have a *1 to many* relation between two tables that I want to combine in a record. Let's say I have one table called **Foo** and another table called **Bar**. **Foo** contains some content and **Bar** contains comments to this content. Now I want to list all contents together with the first comment.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT T0.[Content], T1.[Comment]
FROM [Foo] I0 
    INNER JOIN [Bar] T1 ON T1.[ContentCode] = T0.[Code]
```

That gives me all contents multiple times with many comments. In other words I am saying "Combine all comments with their representing content". What I am trying to achieve is to say "Only combine **one** comment with the content". So I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.[CommentCode], T0.[Content], T1.[Comment]
FROM [Foo] I0 
    INNER JOIN [Bar] T1 ON T1.[ContentCode] = T0.[Code]
```

This works fine. Using `ORDER BY` I can tell the query to use either the first or the last record found in **Bar**.

But for some reason `DISTINCT` is not supported by the database adapter we are forced to use.

Do you face another possibility to limit the results of the right side of the joined relation?

Thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT:**

I am on MSSQL Server 2008 (R2), but accessing it using the SAP Business One DI API. This limits the usage of T-SQL.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Distinct will not work anyway in your scenario as the rows have differet `CommentCode`s

Comment: @Pawal: I cannot use `GROUP BY`, because I need multiple values from the right side table. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly portable way is to query a single comment's ID in a subquery:

```
SELECT  T0.Content
,       T1.Comment
FROM    Foo I0 
JOIN    Bar T1 
ON      T1.ID = 
        (
        SELECT  max(ID)
        FROM    Bar T2
        WHERE   T2.ContentCode = T0.Code
        )
```

If SQL Server executes the subquery for every row, consider this version instead:

```
SELECT  T0.Content
,       T1.Comment
FROM    Foo T0
JOIN    (
        SELECT  ContentCode
        ,       max(ID) as MaxID
        FROM    Bar
        GROUP BY
                ContentCode
        ) filter
ON      filter.ContentCode = T0.ContentCode
JOIN    Bar T1
ON      T1.ID = filter.MaxID
```

Comment: I tried to use subqueries before, but with no luck, that's why I did not mention them. Thanks to you I see what I was missing. I did lead the `ContentCode` back to the content inside the where clause of the subquery. That solved my problem! Thank you :-)

Comment: P.S.: Since subqueries are less performant than joins it would be great to know if there's a way only using one join, anyway :)

Comment: If SQL Server doesn't optimize by itself, you can use a second join to find a single ID for each ContentCode in one go.  Updated in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about 1 comment, why not a subquery like this:

```
SELECT Foo.Content, (SELECT TOP 1 Comment FROM Bar WHERE Bar.ContentCode=Foo.Code) AS [Comment] FROM Foo
```

Comment: This does not work if you are querying multiple fields from the subquery.

Comment: True, this is only to get the comment. However, if more that 1 column is required, Andomar's solution should be enough.